# Multi company, Access Denied : security restrictions

Tags: python, odoo

I have created two company [companyA] and [companyB] with :

Employee A --> [companyA]

Employee B --> [companyB]

The problem is that employee B can't access to all employees even Employee B.
I got this error :

```
"The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

(Document type: Employee, Operation: read) - (Records: [15], User: 13) "
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using standard record rule of hr.employee model of odoo and did not modify it and applied custom domain.

Odoo already providng record rules for multi companines.